# Do grouping of i.i.d random variables change its renormalized sum?

Tags: probability

Let $\lbrace X_i, i \geq 1 \rbrace$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables with zero mean and unit variance. We group this sequence into an sequence of finite sized blocks $\lbrace m_1, m_2...\rbrace$. So that the first $m_1$ random variables are assigned into the first block, and the next $m_2$ are assigned into the second block, etc
\begin{align*} (X_1, X_2, ..., X_{m_1}), (X_{m_1+1}, ..., X_{m_1 + m_2}), ... \end{align*}
We denote $h_n = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} m_i$ as the partial sum of the first n blocks. Let 
\begin{align*} Y_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{m_n}}\sum_{j = h_{n-1} + 1}^{h_n} X_j \end{align*}
be the sum of the n-th block renormalized to unit variance. We let $S_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{h_n}}\sum_{j = 1}^{h_n}X_j$, $U_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{j = 1}^{n}Y_j$. It is easy to see that when $n$ is large, $S_n$ and $U_n$ approach the same normal distribution. The question is: is it true or false that almost surely
\begin{align*} \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n/U_n = 1 \end{align*}
Or informally, if we group i.i.d random variables, is the renormalized sum of the renormalized groups asymptotically equal to the renormalized sum of all the random variables when the group count is large?

Comment: Sorry if I misread, but in $U_n$ shouldn't you have the sum of the $Y_n$'s?

Comment: That was indeed a typo. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: I think this is not true when $m_i \to \infty$ when $i\to \infty$. An example would be $m_i = 2^i$, and the expectation of $S_n/U_n$ goes to zero when $n \to \infty$.